# Why my cursor is not clicking where I did click?

Tags: openlayers

I'm using openlayers 5.3.3 and in my ol-select and ol-draw interactions, I can't manage to know why my cursor is not is not is not at the right place.

After months of research, I didn't managed to find any solution like resizing the map, reset the center, the view, I'm kind of desperate now...

My enterprise doesn't allow me to show you some code I'm sorry

In fact, when I click for example at [1, 1], it clicks at [4, 1] so it doesn't select the good feature or it doesn't draw at the right coordinates.

Comment: Do you reproduce the problem on different web browsers? Do you have the same problem on the example samples (ie: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/popup.html  or https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-and-modify-features.html )?

Comment: the example is working correctly, I got the problem on chrome and that's even worse on other web browsers

Comment: It looks like some performance issues. You should log every events that are triggered after init, and also the events onClick to see if there isn't anything wrong. It will be kind of impossible to help you without any code.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I finally managed to do this by adding a updateSize() and render() to the map in the ngAfterViewInit() method of Angular 6. Problem solved !!